# "Good day" as "良い一日": Yoi ichi-nichi vs Yoi tsuitachi?

Tags: translation, kanji, pronunciation, sentence, greetings

1. Do Japanese say "Good day" as the conventional way of their greetings (?):

> 良い一日。(?)

2. Furthermore, it seems that:

Google pronounced this as

> Yoi ichi-nichi.

But the Google translator shows:

> Yoi tsuitachi.

Comment: Are you familiar with the difference between いちにちand ついたち in general?

Comment: Is there something wrong with こんにちは?

Comment: @A.Ellett you wouldn't use them at the same times as each other... Pretty sure the OP is just unsure of the reading. Though looking again, the lack of を at the end makes it unclear if they understand how it's used.

Comment: @Leebo It seemed to me the OP was asking about the standard greeting, but then confused between how they thought it should be pronounced and Google translator's perception of the matter.

Comment: @A.Ellett In my head, I skipped over "greeting" as just 挨拶, which is not limited to meeting words or parting words. There indeed appear to be layers of confusion.

Comment: Given the OP's mention of "greetings", I think they're confused about how bad machine translation (MT) can be -- I suspect they're looking for "good day" as in こんにちは, and Google's MT engines are struggling with the lack of context.

Answer (score 6):

The *tsuitachi* reading is restricted in meaning, and can only be used to express "the first day of the month".  It's spelled 一日 ("one; first" + "day") in kanji, but it originally comes from [月]{つき}[立ち]{たち} (*tsuki tachi*, "month" + "starting off").

Both readings are possible in the limited context of your sample string:

- 良い一日 → *yoi ichinichi*
- 良い一日 → *yoi tsuitachi*

Which reading you should use depends on your intended context.  Are you talking about "a good day", or are you talking about "a good first day of the month"?

If instead you're trying to translate the greeting *"good day"*, then neither is correct, and you should use the term こんにちは (*konnichi wa*) instead.  See also [the "Translation" section in the Wiktionary entry for "good day"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/good_day#Translations).

Comment: There is also a special kanji [朔]{ついたち}, but I don't know how much it's used in real life.

Comment: @istrasci, the [KDJ entry at Kotobank](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%9C%94%E6%97%A5%E3%83%BB%E6%9C%94%E3%83%BB%E4%B8%80%E6%97%A5-2062784) lists three kanji spellings: 朔日・朔・一日.  Of these, I'm only accustomed to seeing the last one.  A quick check in Google Books (adding "は" to filter for Japanese) finds 216K for the first, 211K for the second, and 9.1M for the last -- but that last one is hard to tell how many are for the ついたち reading.

Comment: Looking for the kanji spellings plus "ついたち", I see 18.1K for 一日, 15.8K for 朔日, and 11.8K for 朔.  ご参照までに。(^^)

Comment: What about "Have a good day"? @EiríkrÚtlendi

Comment: @Scratch---Cat, what are you trying to express when you say _"have a good day"_?  I'm most accustomed to hearing this as a generic kind of _"goodbye"_, usually in a retail setting, in which case the Japanese would be very context dependent -- often something like ありがとうございました (_arigatō gozaimashita_, "thank you [for coming]"), or またお[越]{こ}しください (_mata o-koshi kudasai_, "please come again"), etc.

Comment: @Scratch---Cat:  "Have a good day!"　→　「よい一日を！」

Comment: @istrasci, is that really used?  I don't recall hearing that ever in my three years living in Tokyo in the early aughts.  A quick look at [Google search results for that phrase](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E3%82%88%E3%81%84%E4%B8%80%E6%97%A5%E3%82%92%22) shows that the preponderance of hits are from language-learning sites.  Likewise at [Google books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E3%82%88%E3%81%84%E4%B8%80%E6%97%A5%E3%82%92%22&tbm=bks). If this were a parting phrase in common use in Japanese, I'd expect to have heard it, and I'd expect different search results.